# MongoDB , getting the minimum & maximum of array subset

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Am trying to find a way to get the minimum number of `orders` between 
`2019-03-17` and `2019-03-19` excluding `2019-03-15` from the results ..

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5c8ffdadde62bf097d54ec47"), 
"productId" : "32886845998", 
"orders" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2019-03-15T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "orders" : NumberInt(9)
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2019-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "orders" : NumberInt(21)
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2019-03-18T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "orders" : NumberInt(20)
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2019-03-19T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "orders" : NumberInt(30)
    }
]
```

}

I tried using `$min` and `$max` operator but that didn't help because it iterated through the full array to find maximum & minimum

```
db.products.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        maximum: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$orders",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                    $max: [
                        "$$value",
                        {
                            $cond: [
                                { $gte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2019-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000") ] },
                                "$$this.orders",
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to apply filtering by `orders.date` and then you can apply [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) and [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) on filtered set:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            filteredOrders: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$orders",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2019-03-17T00:00:00.000+0000") ] },
                            { $lte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2019-03-19T00:00:00.000+0000") ] },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            min: { $min: "$filteredOrders.orders" },
            max: { $max: "$filteredOrders.orders" },
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks mickl ,you are awesome as MongoDB